# Not able to load log4net.dll on Windows Server 2012 using Powershell

Tags: powershell, log4net

I have created my own framework for Powershell scripts which I am using on a lot of 2008-servers without issues. Now was the time to try it out on the first 2012-server, but for some reason it fails.

I initially do some checking to ensure that paths are valid, then I try to load the logger

```
try {
    $log = New-Logger -Configuration $log4NetFile -Dll $dll40Path
    Write-Verbose "[Enable-Logger] Using 4.0 DLL" 
} catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
    Write-Verbose "[Enable-Logger] Using 3.5 instead of 4.0 DLL" 
    $log = New-Logger -Configuration $log4NetFile -Dll $dll35Path
} finally {     
    Write-Verbose "[Enable-Logger] Log is $log"
}
```

On all our 2008-servers it loads 4.0 without any issues, but on 2012 the $log-variable is always empty, meaning it cannot load the dll.

To ensure that it has nothing to do with the config file I did try the exact same code on 2008, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Initial workaround

Did check Powershell-version

```
Powershell -Command "Write-Host $psversiontable.psversion"
```

which is 3.0 on the 2012-server. Starting the script with the 2.0 engine like this

```
Powershell -Version 2 -File alertXymon1-region3queues.ps1 -verbose
```

and it worked.

## Final solution

Did some checking today and figured out that the problem was not caused by the DLL, but a code line that is loading the DLL

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($log4netDllPath) | Out-Null
```

Found the post "[Powershell 2.0 script not working in PS 3.0](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6dfccb4b-45c3-4de6-8470-16ae0b60ee07/powershell-20-script-not-working-in-ps-30?forum=winserverpowershell)" which helped me out.

I have now tested the code without [void] on both Powershell 2.0 and 3.0 and it works like a charm